# Is there a limit on HTTP Callouts within 24 hours?

Tags: apex, governorlimits

Can someone please help me out with this:

**"What is exact no of HTTP callouts we can make in 24 hours?"**

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know there is no limit to the number of callouts per 24 hours. But you can only make 100 callouts per transaction. This is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#in_topic_per_transaction_section).

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation:

> A single Apex transaction can make a maximum of 100 callouts to an HTTP request or an API call.

So this applies to both, whether you're making at HTTP callout or hitting an API.

Comment: This does not answer the question which is about a 24-hour limit.

Answer (score 2):

There are no limits against HTTP callouts ie. the outbound calls from your Apex code based on a 24 hr basis. The only limit is,  in a single execution context you can not make more than 100 callouts. 
eg. you can make as many callouts to Google or Linkedin APIs etc or any of your Enterprise Application web services APIs in a day, only thing is you have to take care of how many callouts to these services are allowed on an hourly, daily or monthly basis depending on the limits in these systems as mentioned in their documentations mostly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit to the number of callouts per 24 hours. You can only make 10 callouts per transaction.

Answer (score -1):

Actually I come across a document in which they have given API Request Limits. But i am not sure whether this limitation applies for "HTTP CALLOUT" as well?

Here is link for Doc:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm